# Extract item from JSON string using PHP

Tags: php, json

Lets say I have this JSON string:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/aEjB0uWRf7BN9_0Kkzd0ZK9uqkw\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 76061,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"Y3xTLFF3RLtHXX85JBgzzgp2Enw/T9Y8RT9FLOEgb7ql2XZUv7PpAGU\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#channel",
    "channelId": "UCcB3bcWy0_QK7uPQvTD0LwQ"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

How would I extract the channelId from that as a new variable?

Comment: you don't extract from json. you decode the json  to a native data structure (e.g. php object/array), and then access the data in that array/object like you would any OTHER object/array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to decode json data using `json_decode()`and then you can get values. So do like below:-

```
$json = $json_string;// suppose your json string variable name is $json_string
$std_obj_data = json_decode($json); // now you will get STD class Object
$channel = $std_obj_data->items[0]->id->channelId; // fetch channelId;
```

For example:- https://eval.in/386415

Comment: Said I had to wait 6 minutes :)

Answer (score 4):

You would use `json_decode`:

```
$json = /* your json string */;
$obj = json_decode($json);
$channel = $json->items[0]->id->channelId;
```